# Structure of 3 column layout

Tags: html, css

I would like to make three column layout with CSS. Is it possible that the column items flow in arbitrary order and I only "assign" them to a given column or do they have to be structured so that they first fill the first column, then the second and third? The items have the same width, but different height. Also, the columns may each have vastly different number of items. For example:

(1) For a structure:

```
container:
#1 div .red
#2 div .green
#3 div .green
#4 div .blue
#5 div .red
#6 div .green
#7 div .blue
```

is it possible to style it with CSS so that it falls into three columns like:

```
.red       .green     .blue
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+
|#1      | |#2      | |#4      |
|        | +--------+ |        |
+--------+ +--------+ |        |
+--------+ |#3      | |        |
|#5      | |        | +--------+
|        | +--------+ +--------+
|        | +--------+ |#7      |
|        | |#6      | +--------+
+--------+ |        |
           |        |
           +--------+
```

(2) or does it have to be structured like:

```
container:
#1 div .red
#2 div .red
#3 div .green
#4 div .green
#5 div .green
#6 div .blue
#7 div .blue
```

for:

```
.red       .green     .blue
+--------+ +--------+ +--------+
|#1      | |#3      | |#6      |
|        | +--------+ |        |
+--------+ +--------+ |        |
+--------+ |#4      | |        |
|#2      | |        | +--------+
|        | +--------+ +--------+
|        | +--------+ |#7      |
|        | |#5      | +--------+
+--------+ |        |
           |        |
           +--------+
```

(3) Or even:

```
container for .red:
#1 div .red
#2 div .red
container for .green:
#3 div .green
#4 div .green
#5 div .green
container for .blue:
#6 div .blue
#7 div .blue
```

for:

```
.red           .green         .blue
+------------+ +------------+ +------------+
| +--------+ | | +--------+ | | +--------+ |
| |#1      | | | |#3      | | | |#6      | |
| |        | | | +--------+ | | |        | |
| +--------+ | | +--------+ | | |        | |
| +--------+ | | |#4      | | | |        | |
| |#2      | | | |        | | | +--------+ |
| |        | | | +--------+ | | +--------+ |
| |        | | | +--------+ | | |#7      | |
| |        | | | |#5      | | | +--------+ |
| +--------+ | | |        | | |            |
|            | | |        | | |            |
|            | | +--------+ | |            |
+------------+ +------------+ +------------+
```

How would CSS for the first (1) case look like, if possible?

Comment: It's not easy to get the ordering of #1 using [CSS only "masonry"](https://medium.com/@_jh3y/how-to-pure-css-masonry-layouts-a8ede07ba31a). Options 2 & 3 are the best "CSS only" options.

Comment: I'd suggest going in via flexbox to be honest for something like that..

Comment: With css only you'll have to go with the 3rd structure I believe.

Answer (score 1):

If you can give the container a definite height, you can solve it with flex-box, setting an order for the classes, and adding pseudo-elements to act as "breakers" to force the wrap:

Those psuedo would be invisibles in production; I have made one of them visible just for demo purposes

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px red;
  height: 500px;
}

.container div {
  width: 28%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.container div:nth-child(odd) {
  height: 130px;
}

.container div:nth-child(even) {
  height: 80px;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  /* only for demo */
  background-color: gray;
  /* only for demo */
  height: 100%;
  order: 15;
}

.container:after {
  content: "";
  height: 100%;
  order: 25;
}

.red {
  order: 10;
  background-color: red;
}

.green {
  order: 20;
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  order: 30;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="red"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Very cool! But there is a problem: if I set the height too small, some of the red/green/blue items may "overflow" and create another column. Is it possible to know in advance a height which forms just three columns?

Comment: No, sorry, I don't know of a solution to this point. You need to know beforehand what is the minimum height needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested in attaining your second example where the heights are variable and things just slot in to fill the specified columns then have a look at this

http://codepen.io/hoonin_hooligan/pen/OXbGBP

```
.your-column-wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-gap: 15px;
  -webkit-column-fill: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.your-column-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
 -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
  page-break-inside: avoid;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

This is something I built a while back that could be a good place to start or use for your use case.

Comment: How does it "know" which item goes where? Does it try to fill the columns so that they are all roughly of the same height? In other words, so that the last columns is nicely filled, too, kind of like justified paragraph of text?

Comment: It tries to fill the columns so that they are roughly the same height. How it "knows" which item goes where is just with how the code is marked up. 

For example you could have a 2 column layout using that code and you might have 8 items. Normally if things were equal heights it would put 4 items in each column. But, if you have 2 huge items you might end up with the first column having 3 items (the first 3 you coded) and the second having 5. It makes it pretty predictable knowing what will get put in what column once you know roughly how big each piece of column content will be.

Comment: Is it then possible to control which column an items will go into?

Comment: Yes and no....If you knew that at most your content in the columns would be 1000px high and you have 8 items again..... If you knew that the first 2 items were going to add up to 1000px of height then you can safely assume they will be the first column. Your next 3 items might be 900px - you can safely assume they'll be column 2. The other 3 items would be then be column 3. But in an instance where things might be dynamically coming in and you have no control over how large the content will be then it is up to the code to "decide" what would go where for the most balanced display.

Comment: Ya in that case you don't really have control over what would go where in the dynamic setting, you might be able to get a good idea but you'd never have 100% certainty with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use flex box for this. Just add the `order` property to the items:

e.g. `box1 {order:5;}` will put box 1 in 5th position.

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content:space-around; 
}

.box {
  height: 200px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis:30%;
  margin-top:5px;
}
.box p {
  padding-top: 90px;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  order:4;
}

.blue {
  background: blue;
  order:3;
}

.green {
  background: green;
  order:5;
}

.orange {
  background: orange;
  order:6;
}

.pink {
  background: pink;
  order:2;
}

.purple {
  background: purple;
  order:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box red"><p>1</p></div>
  <div class="box blue"><p>2</p></div>
  <div class="box green"><p>3</p></div>
  <div class="box orange"><p>4</p></div>
  <div class="box pink"><p>5</p></div>
  <div class="box purple"><p>6</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thats a really nice solution! Gunna take that for myself for future use.

Comment: The problem is, there might be many items in the second column and only few in the first. Also, if I go the first route, I don't know in advance how many items there will be in each row so I cannot assign the `order` correctly.

Comment: @EcirHana I have added another answer with some Jquery to randomly shuffle no matter how many items there are. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Ok here is a solution that maybe answers the question better.

You have 3 columns each with an unknown number of items, each you click shuffle the items will order randomly. If you want this to happen when the page loads just remove the `$('#shuffle').click(function() {` and ending `});` and delete the button

```js
$('#shuffle').click(function() {
  $('#box_container .box').each(function() {
    var itemCount = $('.item', this).length;
    $('.item', this).each(function() {
      var order = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemCount) + 1;
      $(this).css('order', order);
    });
  });
});
```

```css
#box_container {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.box {
  color: #ddd;
  text-align: center;
  flex-basis: 30%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
}

.item {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.25);
  height: 50px;
  width: 80%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.red { background: red;}
.blue { background: blue;}
.green { background: green;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="shuffle">Shuffle</button>
<div id="box_container">
  <div class="box red">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box blue">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box green">
    <div class="item item1">1</div>
    <div class="item item2">2</div>
    <div class="item item3">3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```